# Interpreting Impulse Response Function after first differences of logarithm transformation

Tags: interpretation, vector-autoregression, logarithm, impulse-response, differencing

I created an impulse response function from a VAR model. I used data transformed by taking the first difference of logarithms. I am now in trouble with giving a substantive interpretation of the scale of the impulse response function. How can I properly interpret it?

The IRF is an Orthogonal impulse response function, and an example is below:

[image]

As said [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203122/interpreting-var-impulse-response?rq=1):

> An IRF indicates what is the impact of an upward unanticipated one-unit change in the "impulse" variable on the "response" variable over the next several periods (typically 10).

In this case, data are differentiated. Thus, I would say that the values at each time point on the x-axis represent the difference between that time point's value and the previous one. For instance, the value at time $t3$ is the difference between the values at time $t3$ and $t2$ ($t3 - t2$). This difference is then logged.

Therefore, I would interpret the above chart, for example, as follows, starting from the first time period on the x-axis:

*A one-log-unit increase from time $t-1$ to time $t0$ in the impulse variable $s1$, leads to a change of about 0.002 log-units in the response variable $s2$ from the time period $t-1$ to $t$.*

*The maximum effect can be seen at time $t3$, where one-log-unit increase from the time $t-1$ to $t0$ in the impulse variable $s1$, leads to about 0.005 log-units change in the response variable $s2$ from period $t2$ to $t3$.*

I could then transform back the logged units by taking the exponential of the values. In this case, I would say, for instance:

*The increase in the response $s2$ at time $t1$ is about 1 ($exp(0.002)$) for each 2.718282 units increase ($exp(1)$) in the impulse variable $s1$.*

Is that correct?

There are similar questions on CrossValidated, like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313743/interpretation-of-log-transformed-first-differences-in-svar-models) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512325/how-do-i-transform-first-differenced-impulse-response-functions-back-into-levels), but they are still without answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your impulse response function graph shows time evolution of how *s2* responds to a shock that originated in *s1*. A one-unit (one-standard-deviation of *s1*) change (shock) in your variable *s1* at time *t* results in a change in your dependent variable *s2* whose magnitude is shown on the y axis of your graph.

For example, your log differences *s2* would go up by 0.002 at t=1 in response to a shock that originates in *s1* whose magnitude is one standard deviation of *s1*.